# Check if only one GET Parameter is Defined?

Tags: php, if-statement, parameters, get, isset

I have some code, essentially containing a page-specific header, that should only load if only one GET parameter is defined in my URL.

For example, if I want the header only to show if "thisonly" parameter in the URL is set, if the URL was:

http://www.example.com?thisonly=w&thisone=q&thistwo=q&thisthree=q

Previously I have been using this code to check:

```
    if((isset($_GET[thisonly])) && (!isset($_GET[thisone])) && (!isset($_GET[thistwo])) && (!isset($_GET[thisthree]))) {
    // Run this code
    }
```

In the case above, the code would not run, since those other parameters are set.

However, this will be a hassle to update, especially if I end up adding more parameters, and will have to go back and add to this code to make sure they also are not set.

Is there some way to shorten it down to the equivalent of

```
    if((isset($_GET[thisonly])) && (!isset($_GET[nothingelse]))) {
    // Run this code
    }
```

E.g., if "thisonly" is the only parameter set, and no other parameters are set, then run the code?

Any help appreciated -- thanks!

Comment: `[thisonly]` gets treated as a [**constant**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php). Wrap them in quotes `['thisonly']` etc.

Comment: Just so I understand, How can the way I have it lead to unwanted results? I did read your link, however I am not sure why to put it in quotes vs not.. Does quotes around it mean that http://www.example.com?TeSt=true would register the same as http://www.example.com?test=true

Comment: Try it out without quotes in conjunction with John's answer below. If it works out, great. If it throws an error, then you'll know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(count($_GET) === 1 && isset($_GET['thisonly'])) {
```

This checks to see if `$_GET` is an array with only one element and it is `$_GET['thisonly']`.

Comment: One quick followup -- I have a "securevalue" function (including pregreplace, mysql_real_escape_string and trim) that I've been individually applying to each $_GET variable as well. Will this logic work to secure all $_GET values, rather than securing them one by one?: if(isset($_GET)){securevalue($_GET);}

Comment: There are PHP functions that you can use to apply a function to a an array. Look at `array_map()` for starters.

Comment: I see; would my way work also though? It seems like using the mapping function would end up using much more code than the one line I referenced previously, " if(isset($_GET)){securevalue($_GET);} "

Comment: `securevalue` would need to be defined and would take much more than one line so it won't work like you would like it to